# Какую БД выбрать с возможностью переноса на другой ПК под C# (.net core & EF core)?

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework-core

Доброе. Я только начинающий в .net и в программировании в частности (7 месяцев учусь).
Имеется проект - бот - для discord (типа бота телеграмм). К нему требовалось прикрутить базу данных и выбор пал на MS SQL server. Моя беда заключается в том, что я хотел бы добавить возможность переноса этого
приложения на другой ПК или сервер, но не знаю что мне делать.

Какой вариант будет лучше - БД с возможностью переноса (если этот вариант, то какая БД и как подключить EF core?), *ИЛИ* что-то другое?

Comment: Если нужно свободно таскать приложение с БД - значит, нужна какая-то embedded СУБД. Вроде самая из них популярная (могу ошибаться) - SQLite.

Comment: _как подключить EF core?_ - на nuget.org есть пакеты для всех популярных СУБД.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужна компактная БД для приложения, то SQLite неплохой выбор. Начните с нее.

Как ее подключить посмотрите здесь [SQLite EF Core Database Provider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) (обратите внимания на некоторые ограничения). Или тут [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/).